# WebDeploy 3.6 won't connect with TLS 1.0 disabled

Tags: tls, iis-8.5

Recently I had my servers audited for PCI compliance.

As part of this I was picked up for not having TLS 1.0 disabled as per:

http://blog.varonis.com/ssl-and-tls-1-0-no-longer-acceptable-for-pci-compliance/

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1_Summary_of_Changes.pdf

When I disable TLS 1.0 using [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) Web Deploy breaks.

Has anyone found a WebDeploy 3.6 fix for using WebDeploy without TLS 1.0?

Answer (score 6):

We added registry keys to force the .NET app pool over to TLS 1.2. This was to allow an app to talk to Salesforce after SF issued a critical update disabling TLS 1.0. The registry keys apply to the whole server as opposed to a single site, unfortunately. The build broke for the reason you indicate above. This worked for us:

[Getting WebDeploy working after disabling insecure Ciphers like SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10)

Excerpt:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]`
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]`
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001