# Force Remote IIS Manager to connect through TLS 1.2

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, windows-server-2019

I've setup a new IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019 Core 1809 (ltsc).

I have setup the `wmsvc` service and confirmed that it is working. I was able to connect from a Remote Administration Server (Windows Server 2019) to the IIS Server via the IIS Manager through the `wmsvc` port, and the developers were able to use `WebDeploy`, which also uses `wmsvc`, from their Windows 10 Machines.

I then went on to harden my Server according to the [Qualys SSL guidelines](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). To get a very good score on cipher suites etc. I used [IISCryptoCli](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/)

I used the following command on my IIS:

```
IISCryptoCli.exe /backup BackupCrypto.reg /template strict /reboot
```

Why did I use the `strict` template instead of the `best` template? Because it is the only one that disables [the deprecated TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1](https://notifications.qualys.com/product/2020/06/24/deprecating-tlsv1-0-and-tlsv1-1)

Now the thing is - since then I can not connect to my IIS Manager from a RemoteServer, and neither can the Developers use `WebDeploy` anymore. We always get the following error when trying to connect:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
> a send.

I found the [following site](http://woshub.com/remote-iis-management-in-windows-server-2012/) which describes the problem, and it says I have to add the following registry keys to to the remote machines that want to connect, to force a TLS 1.2 protocol:

- `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`
- `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

which I did and then rebooted the machines, however - still no luck.

I then used `IISCrypto` to set the TLS protocol to `best` on my Remote Administration Servers and rebooted them - still not working.

after that I set my IIS to the `best` template which reenabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and rebooted my IIS - still not working.

What else can I do? How can I have only TLS 1.2 enabled, and still have a working IIS Remote Management through `wmsvc`?

**Update:**

I am starting to think that the TLS change was not the fault.

I reverted the following back:

- I reset IIS completely by uninstalling `WAS` and `Web-Server` Feature, I basically have a completely clean IIS (I can confirm that because `administration.config` and `applicationhost.config` is reset to the default state, after I reinstalled `WAS` and `Web-Server`.) Also the `WMSVC` got completely reset during this operation
- I uninstalled basically every program (including all .net core bundles, WebDeploy etc.)
- I also set all TLS stuff back to default.

still the problem persists. I find a lot of stuff on the internet where people have the same problem, but no solution... hmmm..

**Update 2:**

I set up a new IIS now, and made a backup basically between every step.
It's really as soon as I set the `strict` template of `IISCrypto`, that everything breaks. As soon as I implement the Default Registry entries, everything works again.

... And now all of a sudden, it works when I use `SchUseStrongCrypto` in the two registry Keys. Strange. But anyhow I'm happy now. Looks like on my first IIS something messed up something in the registry that never got recovered.

Comment: For reference, the previous duplicate question that references the solution that failed to help here: https://serverfault.com/questions/756068/webdeploy-3-6-wont-connect-with-tls-1-0-disabled

Comment: Wait, after you reverted you are not back with a working system? Please compare your registry backup (saved when applying the template) with your current state!

Comment: @anx the `best` template is not fully reverted. before no CipherSuite and TLS Protocol was disabled. I can go back to the default settings to confirm it's working, but the problem would still exist then, because the strict SSL Support is a must for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have two 2019 servers here with IIS installed. The server A has the management service installed. On Server B I can use IIS Manager to connect to server A with the default Windows TLS settings.

I changed the TLS settings on server A using the IIS Crypt GUI to the following:

[image: IIS Crypto]

As you can see, only TLS 1.2 is enabled, all cipher suites are enabled but some could be disabled as well.

I am still able to connect from server B to server A.

I haven't tried `WebDeploy`

Comment: Is it an IIS on the LTSC though? Version 1809? I suspect that only this and earlier versions could have the problem.

Comment: Both are Eval Version, because I just set them up to test this. Build 17763 - 180914-1434 and not Core, I think the IIS Crypt GUI may run on Core.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the web management role, reboot and re-add it. Enable the remote management registry key and do the WINRM service startup and set it to automatic.

I am thinking that if you install the web management service while the depricated TLS is still enabled, it locks into that and won't let go.

I have no issues if I set my servers to TLS 1.2 only, reboot and then install the web managemnt role.